# C++ (No C++11) callback to a class getter function via std::map

Tags: c++, reflection, callback

I am trying to create a parsing engine to fetch data from a Google protocol buffer (GPB) library in C++.
I parse the object from serialized data and get an object from the `Config` class. I would like to retrieve data
from this `config` object which contains arrays and multiple nested objects and references (remember GPB).
Rather than hard-coding:

```
if command == "config.wireless.0.ap.0.essid":
    return config.wireless(0).ap(0).essid();
else if command == "config.ip"
    return config.ip();
```

I want to create a map for each level of the tree:

```
std::map<std::string, Callback> map;
map["ip"] = config.ip;
```

Then evaluate each token (`.` delimited) with the appropriate map to fetch callback.

*Problem / TRDL;*: Having an issue mapping getter functions from classes to callbacks.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class AP
{
public:
    AP() : _key(0), _essid("my ssid!") {}
    int key() { return _key; }
    std::string essid() { return _essid; }
private:
    std::string _essid;
    int _key;
};

class Wireless
{
public:
    Wireless() : _key(0)
    {
        AP ap;
        _aps.push_back(ap);
    }
    int key() { return _key; }
    AP &ap(int index) { return _aps[index]; }
private:
    std::vector<AP> _aps;
    int _key;
};

class Config
{
public:
    typedef std::string *(*FnPtr)(void);

    Config() : _ip("10.0.0.1")
    {
        Wireless wireless;
        _wireless.push_back(wireless);
    }

    Wireless &wireless(int index) { return _wireless[index]; }
    std::string ip() { return _ip; }
private:
    std::vector<Wireless> _wireless;
    std::string _ip;
};



void compute(const std::string &cmd, Config &config)
{
    std::map<std::string, Config::FnPtr> fn_map;
    fn_map["ip"] = config.ip;

    std::cout << fn_map[cmd]() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Config config;
    std::string cmd = "ip";

    compute(cmd, config);

    return 0;
}
```

Without using C++11 `std::function/bind` (unfortunately) how can I get this behavior to work? Someone mentioned that C++ does not allow reflection (what I am trying to do) so hopefully there's a way around this.

Additionally, I am using syntax similar to SNMP, if anyone knows how SNMP translates the strings `mywireless.0.interface.1.ip` to the appropriate function to grab the value I would be interested in that.

Comment: Your `typedef` looks incorrect. I think you want `typedef std::string (*FnPtr)(void);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function` and `bind` were originally added as part of TR1, so even if you can't use C++11, maybe including `<tr1/functional>` is an option?

If so

```
#include <tr1/functional>

// ...

void compute(const std::string &cmd, Config &config)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::tr1::function<std::string()> > fn_map;
    fn_map["ip"] = std::tr1::bind(&Config::ip, config);

    std::cout << fn_map[cmd]() << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39a9077fd30398b1)

Comment: This works great, however, the return of each member function for different classes will be different so the line: `std::map<std::string, std::tr1::function<std::string()> > fn_map;` fails because it expects to return std::string. The issue is that I have no control over the class objects return type. Any way around this?

Comment: After reviewing this I don't see any possible way to do this, maybe in C11 but not in 03. The issue I have is the return value of these functions can be anything from a 3rd-parties class reference, pointer or any primitives.. Using templates would not be the way to do as I haven't found a way for this to work. Is there a nice way to solve the solution I have? SNMP string paths to resolve class depth. `"ip.0.wireless.0.ssid" -> ip(0).wireless(0).ssid();`

Comment: @dstealth564574 No, the solution depends on the return types being common across all the functions you want to invoke. A possible solution might be create wrappers for the functions that have different return types and convert them all to a common type, `std::string` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem:

```
std::map<std::string, Config::FnPtr> fn_map;
    fn_map["ip"] = config.ip;
```

`Config::FnPtr` is a:

```
typedef std::string *(*FnPtr)(void);
```

Described in English, this is "a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and which returns a pointer to a `std::string`".

"config.ip" is "a pointer to a member method of class Config that takes no arguments and which returns a `std::string`".

The two are not the same, hence your error.

This is not just the fact that you likely meant your typedef to be "typedef std::string (*FnPtr)(void)". Even if you fix this, this will still not work. This is because you will have:

"A function that takes no arguments and which returns a pointer to a `std::string`."

and

"A pointer to a member method of class Config that takes no arguments and which returns a `std::string`."

The two are still not the same, and one cannot be assigned to the other.

So, what can you do? Well, that depends on what your exact intentions are, here. I'm going to guess that you probably want something like this:

First, change your typedef:

```
typedef std::string (Config::*FnPtr)(void);
```

This declares `FnPtr` as "a pointer to a member method of class Config that takes no arguments, and which returns a `std::string`".

Then, rewrite your compute() method:

```
void compute(const std::string &cmd, Config &config)
{
    std::map<std::string, Config::FnPtr> fn_map;
    fn_map["ip"] = &Config::ip;

    std::cout << (config.*fn_map[cmd])() << std::endl;
}
```

The description in English of `&Config::ip` is "a pointer to a member of Class Config named `ip`". This member happens to be "A method that takes no arguments and which returns a std::string".

The expression `(config.*fn_map[cmd])()` can be described, in English as: access a member of class instance named `config` which is specified by the expression "fn_map[cmd]".

Based on the descriptions I gave you, you should be able to figure out, by yourself, why this works.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem. He wants to be able to store member functions of different classes (albeit having the same signature) in the `map`, for instance `Config::ip()` and `AP::essid()`. That's why you need some kind of type erasure solution, like `std::function`.

Comment: std::function won't help. When you have a non-static class member function, as opposed to a plain function or a static class member function, essentially the class itself is a part of the function's signature, from a certain point of view. So, no two member functions from different classes will ever have the same signature.

Comment: ... one way around that is to derive both classes from a common superclass that defines these functions as virtual, and implemented in the subclass. Then, you can use this approach, referencing the superclass's member functions.

Comment: Of course, `std::function` alone isn't sufficient, you use `std::bind` to bind the instance that you want to invoke the member function on before passing it to `std::function`, thus removing that dependency. And introducing an inheritance hierarchy for this sole purpose, amongst otherwise unrelated classes, is a terrible idea.